# Change column details in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows.

```
mydata =
   xxx  yyy zzz nnn ddd mmm
0  0   10     5    5   5  5
1  0   9      2    3   4  4
2  1   8      8    7   9  0
```

Now, I want to change the values in the column `xxx` in a way, if it contains `0` add `n` else if `1` add `y`. So, output should look as follows.

```
mydata =
   xxx  yyy zzz nnn ddd mmm
0  n   10     5    5   5  5
1  n   9      2    3   4  4
2  y   8      8    7   9  0
```

Is it possible to do such data changes in pandas? Or are there any python library I can use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lambda` with `apply`:

```
mydata['xxx'] = mydata['xxx'].apply(lambda x: 'n' if x == 0 else 'y')
```

Or if you have values other than `0` and `1`:

```
mydata['xxx'] = mydata['xxx'].apply(lambda x: 'n' if x == 0 else 'y' if x == 1 else x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get a warning as follows `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`. Do you know why that happens?

Comment: You can ignore the warning or use `mydata.loc[:, 'xxx'] = mydata.loc[:, 'xxx'].apply(lambda x: 'n' if x == 0 else 'y')` or the other function but with `loc` as well.